# mongodb count two condition one time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to count two query like below:

```
1. data[k]['success'] = common.find({'url': {"$regex": k}, 'result.titile':{'$ne':''}}).count()
2. data[k]['fail'] = common.find({'url': {"$regex": k}, 'result.titile':''}).count()
```

I think it would be more efficient if mongodb can work like below:

```
result = common.find({'url': {"$regex": k})
count1 = result.find({'result.titile':{'$ne':''}}) 
count2 = result.count() - count1
//result do not have find or count method, just for example
```

Two count are basing same search condition`{'url': {"$regex": k}`, splited by `{'result.titile':{'$ne':''}}` or not.
Is there some build-in way to do these without writing custom js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` method would be the preferred one if at all your client supports it.

You could also aggregate as below:

- [*$match*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the docs which have the urls.
- [*$group*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by the `_id` as `null`, and take the `$sum` of all documents. We need those documents, to get the sum of those which do not have a title, so just accumulate them using the [*$push*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator.
- [*$unwind*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the documents.
- `$match` those which do not have a title.
- `$group`, and get the `$sum`.
- `$project` the desired result.

sample code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"url":{"$regex":k}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "count_of_url_matching_docs":{$sum:1},
         "docs":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$unwind:"$docs"},
{$match:{"docs.result.titile":{$ne:""}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "count_of_url_matching_docs":{$first:"$count_of_url_matching_docs"},
         "count_of_docs_with_titles":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "count_of_docs_with_titles":"$count_of_docs_with_titles",
           "count_difference":{$subtract:[
                                       "$count_of_url_matching_docs",
                                       "$count_of_docs_with_titles"]}}}
])
```

Test data:

```
db.t.insert([
{"url":"s","result":{"titile":1}},
{"url":"s","result":{"titile":""}},
{"url":"s","result":{"titile":""}},
{"url":"s","result":{"titile":2}}
])
```

Test Result:

```
{ "count_of_docs_with_titles" : 2, "count_difference" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with a conditional key for grouping via [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```js
common.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "url": { "$regex": k } } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$ne": [ "$result.title", "" ] },
                "then": "success",
                "else": "fail"
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

However it is actually more efficient to run both queries in parallel if your environment supports it, such as with nodejs

```js
async.parallel(
  [
    function(callback) {
      common.count({ 
        "url": { "$regex": k },
        "result.title": { "$ne": "" } 
      }, function(err,count) {
          callback(err,{ "success": count });
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      common.count({ 
        "url": { "$regex": k },
        "result.title": ""
      }, function(err,count) {
          callback(err,{ "fail": count });
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err,results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
  }
)
```

Which makes sense really since each item is not being tested and each result can actually run on the server at the same time.